# Skip disabled buttons when tabbing - keynav

Tags: javascript, extjs, keyboard, extjs4.2

Using ExtJS 4.2 Is there a simple way to skip over disabled buttons when tabbing?

I started implementing a whole custom keynav to get around this but it's growing into a monstrosity to handle any other type of component that could get tabbed onto.

I googled around and couldn't find anything though it seems like it would be a normal thing not to tab onto disabled (unfocusable) buttons. Has anyone else implemented something like this?

Comment: normally disabled buttons are skipped, did you set the disabled property of the html element?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ExtJS buttons have a child element `btnEl` that gets missed when disabled state is set, I worked out some overrides to handle this:

```
// force disabled buttons to be untabbable
Ext.override(Ext.button.Button, {

    afterRender: function() {
        var me = this;

        if (me.disabled) {
            me.btnEl.dom.removeAttribute('tabIndex');
        }
    },

    enable: function(silent) {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.removeClsWithUI('disabled');
        if (me.rendered) {
            me.el.dom.setAttribute('tabIndex', me.tabIndex);
            me.btnEl.dom.setAttribute('tabIndex', me.tabIndex);
        }

        return me;
    },

    disable: function(silent) {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.addClsWithUI('disabled');
        me.removeClsWithUI(me.overCls);
        if (me.rendered) {
            me.el.dom.removeAttribute('tabIndex');
            me.btnEl.dom.removeAttribute('tabIndex');
        }

        if (me.btnInnerEl && Ext.isIE7m) {
            me.btnInnerEl.repaint();
        }

        return me;
    }

});
```